# Perl mySql data to JSON file

Tags: mysql, json, perl

Hello i am trying to save mysql detail in json file
how to save mysql detail in json format ?

my perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $file = $db->SelectRow("SELECT f.*, s.*, u.usr_login as file_usr_login, u.usr_profit_mode
                              FROM (Files f, Servers s)
                              LEFT JOIN Users u ON f.usr_id = u.usr_id
                              WHERE f.file_code=?
                              AND f.srv_id=s.srv_id",$f->{id});
```

how to save `$file` detail in json ?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm#SYNOPSIS

Comment: The code you showed will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $file = $db->SelectRow(
    q[SELECT f.*, s.*, u.usr_login as file_usr_login, u.usr_profit_mode
                              FROM (Files f, Servers s)
                              LEFT JOIN Users u ON f.usr_id = u.usr_id
                              WHERE f.file_code=?
                              AND f.srv_id=s.srv_id], $f->{id}
);

use JSON;

my $json = new JSON;

my $file_in_json = $json->encode($file);
```